# OpenGL Getting Shader Attached to Program

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is there a way to access the shaders attached to a program? That is, given a program, can I do something like:

```
vertexShader = getVertexShaderFromProgram(program);
```

(I would like to log shader compilation status within my function that validates my program, but I only keep a reference to the program, not the shaders.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [`glGetAttachedShaders()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetAttachedShaders.xhtml) to get the names of the shaders attached to the given program object.
2. [`glGetShaderiv( ..., GL_SHADER_TYPE, ... )`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetShader.xhtml) to get the type (vertex, geometry, fragment) of shader.
3. [`glGetShaderiv( ..., GL_SHADER_SOURCE_LENGTH, ... )`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetShader.xhtml) on each shader name to figure out how long the source is.
4. [`glGetShaderSource()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetShaderSource.xhtml) to get the source string for each attached shader.

**EDIT**: If all you need are the shader names & types you can stop after step 2.

Comment: What happens if the shader objects have been deleted?