# Keeping Shader Source Code Hidden

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The following StackOverflow response explains several different ways to get source code from a shader after the shader source code has been introduced into the application.  While, typically people are not worried about shader code being read (hence text file reads for the most part), occasionally we are.

[Retrieving Shader Source Code from GLProgram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537415/opengl-getting-shader-attached-to-program)

Therefore, if we are concerned with keeping Shader Source code from being read, then what approach can actually be taken to prevent this?  I don't particularly want what's being done in the shader code to be browsed.  If certain mathematical components are desired to be hidden, then do I have to pull those out from the shader source and do them locally in the code?

**Edit:**

While I understand that someone who wants to get information from something with enough effort will probably accomplish the task, it is always nice to make such tasks something that is not trivial.

Comment: It's "not trivial" to get an Android program's *executable*. Anyone who's serious enough to get access to an Android program's storage will also be serious enough to jail-break their Android device and snatch your shader out of the memory.

Comment: "*Retrieving Shader Source Code from GLProgram*" This question is about how *your code* can do it for shaders *you create*. Some other program wouldn't have easy access to the OpenGL context, so they wouldn't be able to simply call those functions. So it's not clear who exactly you're trying to protect your code from.

Comment: Although all you said is true, getting the apk (buy the app) and peeking inside is relatively easy. Although securing your shader code is not worth your time anyways. I would spend more time securing my monetization channel.

Comment: @NicolBolas The question that was being brought up here though was for someone working off the same EGLContext.  It would be part of a library that returns a program code to be used with the users existing textures.  It would be to protect all users using the library from looking at the code.

Comment: Ok, fair enough guys. Appreciate the retort for securing shader source code. Certainly clears up any misconceptions that I might have had on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question that was being brought up here though was for someone working off the same EGLContext. It would be part of a library that returns a program code to be used with the users existing textures. It would be to protect all users using the library from looking at the code.

So you want to protect your program from itself. Be grateful that OpenGL's shader compilation/linking model *just so happens* to allow you to do that. Because if it had been defined any other way, you couldn't do this.

You can use the shader/program distinction. After linking a program object, the shader objects you used to build it are *completely* irrelevant. You can detach them with [calls to `glDetachShader`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDetachShader.xml). Then you can delete the shaders and just return the program.

Indeed, you should *always* do this; otherwise, OpenGL will keep around a pointless copy of the shader strings until you delete the program.

Comment: Oh!  Well, then.  That is a different story.  That is excellent news to hear Nicol.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Well it is granted such kind of protection in any environment (OS).

Answer (score 1):

You can insert place holders and replace them during runtime. But not matter what you do, if someone is really interested in your code they will eventually read it.

EDIT: Another option that also crossed my mind just now it to use precompiled shaders using `glShaderBinary`. But it is probably the same, just one step more for the attacker and not all platforms return any supported binary formats (`GL_NUM_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS`).

*Just to make things clear, it is not worth you time, there are probably other areas in your program where you should spend this time.*

Comment: You are referencing using uniforms that are changed externally instead of doing calculations directly in the shader code?

Comment: With placeholders I mean leaving some well-known text that is replaced during runtime before compiling the program. This way you can scatter the remaining code in your native program flow. But again, if you leave a constant string in your binary code, it can be easily read anyways.

Comment: Oh, using a form of misdirection essentially.  Leading them to think that the source is what it is, but then replacing it from native code later.  Interesting, yeah.  But as you pointed out, they could still pull it out with a glGetShaderSource call during runtime if they wanted anyway.

Comment: Yes, I added another possibility, but it is almost as easy to "break" as using plain text (although you gain a bonus, your program loads faster).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike CPU application binaries, GPU shader binary compatibility is still in its infancy as instruction sets have not been standardized. It's possible to use binary shader programs on many GPUs, but portability between different devices (even those containing GPU IP from the same company) can be tricky.

The ["How can I use GLSL ES shader binaries in my application?"](http://forum.imgtec.com/discussion/2391/how-can-i-use-glsl-es-shader-binaries-in-my-application#latest) FAQ item on the PowerVR Insider website details the technical challenges of using binary shaders on PowerVR devices.